# Is there a way an NON-elevated process can copy a file to a protected directory?

Tags: c++, windows, uac

I am fine with it asking the user for elevation when it is ready to copy a file.  The program that needs to do the copying cannot run elevated (it looses many important environment variables and I am not in a position to change the way it is started).  My fallback will be to have it spawn a process with elevation that actually does the file copy, but I would prefer not to have to add yet another exe to what I am working on.

Comment: Of course not, that would make UAC pointless.

Comment: You misunderstand.  I am fine with windows asking for elevation.  I was hoping there was a way to elevate the program at that time.

Comment: AFAIK Programs cannot be elevated after they have started.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081945/can-a-process-elevate-itself-after-startup?rq=1) might help.

Comment: Yeah I figured I couldn't elevate it, but was hoping to spare myself the pain of making a new exe, getting it into CI, and then having to get it into the installer.  If someone wants to say it is impossible in an answer, I will accept their answer.

Comment: You could launch a new copy of yourself, elevated, with a special command line argument that turns it into a slave process.  But since Explorer allows you to elevate to do a file copy, using the Windows Shell functions, such as [`IFileOperation.CopyItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [COM Elevation Moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx) to instantiate the [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx) shell interface, then all file operations done with that interface will be elevated without having to elevate the calling process, or having to create a separate EXE/process to handle the file access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `ShellExecute` a copy of your program using the `runas` verb. That will cause the copy to be elevated. This elevated process can then do the thing.

Typically you pass a copy of yourself a command line option indicating you want to do that protected thing:

> ShellExecute(0, "runas" "Frobber.exe", "-doThatThingThatRequiresElevation", "");

Comment: Although this does work (I use it myself when displaying UI dialogs that need elevated rights), it can be a PITA if your app's startup code needs a lot of tweaking to avoid creating things it is not going to be using when run in this special mode.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted wisdom is that this is not possible because you cannot elevate a program as it is running.  Also see:  [Can a process elevate itself after startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081945/can-a-process-elevate-itself-after-startup?rq=1)